# php 7 put data from csv column into a set

Tags: php, data-structures, php-7

I need to read a csv file and put all of the data in a particular column into a Set ( so as to eliminate duplicates ).  I have earched through the questions here and I see some similar answers for arrays but I am not well enough versed in php to extrapolate from these examples to my use case.

Specifically, I need to grab a csv file of all the cars towed by the city of Chicago.  Then I need to loop through the 'Make' column and grab all of the makes.  I do not want to include duplicates so I'm thinking a Set ( which I understand php7 supports) would be an appropriate data structure.

I'm not concerned at all with efficiency at this point, more with simplicity as this is part of a homework assignment.   I had the option of just manually going through and picking out the makes but thought that would be an easy out.

I guess array is ok since someone was kind enough to inform me about these two functions.

```
[code]


     $towFileString = file_get_contents("put link here");
file_put_contents('tow-data.csv', $towFileString);

$file = fopen('tow-data.csv', 'rb');
$csvArray = array();

while(!feof($file)){
    $csvArray = fgetcsv($file);
}

$allMakes = array_column($csvArray, 'Make');

$uniqueMakes = array_unique($allMakes);
```

When I run the program, however, PHP tells me this:
Warning:  array_column() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given

So it is telling me that the array I just created is really a boolean.

I was hoping you could give me some insight into why this is the case

NOTE:  I am not asking you to do my work for me.  I'd just like a few pointers to get me started in the right direction.

Comment: Google "php csv". There are CSV-related functions in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the values of the 'make' column into a seperate array using the array_column function, like this:

```
$allMakes = array_column($towedCars, 'make');
```

and then run array_unique on it, which will eliminate all the duplicates:

```
$uniqueMakes = array_unique($allMakes);
```

Comment: I attempted a solution using your two functions.  However, I ran into an issue which I edited my question above to include.  Could you please take a look for me?